# Spring Security doesn't work with Http11NioProtocol

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, tomcat7

I'm modifying an app to use Active Directory, using the Spring Security model. All is working well on my local Tomcat 7 installation but on our UNIX machine it stops working.

The symptoms seem to suggest that the Spring Security filter is not being invoked, but there are no exceptions or other indications in the logs (with debug). By trial and error I found that the reason for this is because in the UNIX server.xml install I have:

```
<Connector port="8083" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           proxyName="myproxy.com" scheme="http"
/>
```

whereas on my local install I have:

```
<Connector port="8083" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           proxyName="myproxy.com" scheme="http"
/>
```

The Connector protocol appears to be the problem, if I use HTTP/1.1 on UNIX then all is well.

So my question is, what do I have to do to get things working with Http11NioProtocol?

Tomcat 7.0.42
Java 1.7.0.45
Spring Security 4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, as I look at this question I think 'what rubbish'. The problem I was experiencing was due to an incompatible version of Atmosphere - once updated the problem with Spring Security went away and we were able to use Http11NioProtocol.